# Equivalent Definitions of Hodge Structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, filtrations

I have read some materials on Hodge structures and all of them state the equivalence of definitions from the following perspectives: (suppose that we are considering a Hodge structure of weight $n\in \mathbb{Z})$

1. Hodge decomposition:
   $$V_\mathbb{C}=\bigoplus_{p+q=n}V^{p,q}\quad \text{with}\quad V^{p,q}=\overline{V^{q,p}},$$
2. Hodge filtration:
   $$V_\mathbb{C}\supset\cdots\supset F^{p-1}\supset F^p\supset\cdots\quad\text{such that}\quad V_\mathbb{C}=F^p\oplus\overline{F^{q+1}}\quad\text{and}\quad F^p\cap \overline{F^{q+1}}=0 \text{ for }p+q=n.$$

In order to show the equivalence we need $F^p=\bigoplus_{i\geq p}V^{i,n-i}.$ This is clear if we know the Hodge decomposition(i.e. by definition). But if we know the Hodge filtration how can we see this equality?

Comment: Are you missing a ${}^{p,q}$ exponent? Should it be $V_{\mathbb C}^{p,q} = F^p \oplus \overline{F^{q+1}}$?

Comment: @red_trumpet Actually $V_\mathbb{C}^{p, q}$ is defined to be $F^p\cap \overline{F^{q}}$ for $p+q=n$. I thought it was clear. But I don't know how to show $F^p=\oplus_{i\geq p}V^{i, n-i}$. Once we know this the equivalence is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $\mathrm{Gr}^p_FV_\mathbb{C}:=F^p/F^{p+1}\cong V_\mathbb{C}^{p,q}:=F^p\cap\overline{F^q}.$

We may consider the map $\varphi: F^p/F^{p+1}\rightarrow F^p\cap\overline{F^q}$ which is a well-defined linear transformation. Being an isomorphism is directly from the condition $F^p\cap \overline{F^{q+1}}=0$.